# How big payload we can send in single transaction in Hyperledger Fabric. How many assets we can put in a single transaction?

Tags: performance, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

1)  How big payload in terms of size, we can add in a single transaction in Hyperledger Fabric. I have millions of assets, ingesting into Fabric network. Maximum assets(Key-Value) can be added into the single transaction are 1000(Correct if I am wrong). Can we customize this number, so that a high number of an asset can be added in a single transaction in a short time?

2) What is an efficient way to trigger the huge number of an asset into the network?

I am trying to improve performance in terms of TPS and latency. I have already added necessary indexes and composite key (Couch DB)

Answer (score 3):

1) At the transport level, Fabric currently has a 100MB limit.  It cannot be changed.  There is some additional overhead added in some of the transaction wrappers, so to be safe, the total size of the key/values you write plus the size of the key/values you read should be no greater than ~90MB.

2) You can try implementing an operation on your chaincode which allows for multiple assets to be created.